# Nonlinear Recursion - Count Shapes

Tags: c#, recursion

I have to create a program that uses recursion to count the number of *shapes* stored in a text file which will then output the number of *shapes* in the file.

The text file will contain a rectangular arrangement of dots and X's.

The X's form *shapes* that are separated by space. The dots represent empty space which separate one shape from another. To define a *shape*, any given X belongs to the same *shape* as any other X that is above, below,  left and to its right.  Any two X's on a diagonal are not connected.

For example, in this text file there will be 6 shapes:

```
18
44
............................................
............................................
.......XXXXXX...............................
.....XXXXXXXXXXXX...........X...............
....XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.........XXXXXXXXXX......
.......XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.......................
...............XXXXXX.......................
...............XXXX.......XXXXXXX...........
...........XXXX..........XXX..XXXX..........
......XXXXXXXXXXXXXX........................
.......XXXXXXXXXXXX.........................
............................................
.............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.........
.............XX.................XXX.........
.............XX...XXXXXXXX......XXX.........
.............XX...XXXXXXXX......XXX.........
.............XX.................XXX.........
.............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.........
```

This is the code I have so far to count the number of *shapes* however it does not seem to be able to correctly count them as I keep getting 1 instead of 6 for my final output.

```
    namespace MazeWin
    {
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        //private class variables
        char[,] CountShapes;
        int rows;
        int cols;
        Grid grid;
        int Counter = 0;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //global variables
            rows = 0;
            cols = 0;
        }

        private void mnuFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get file from Open Dialog box
            OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //load the file
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fd.OpenFile());
                rows = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                cols = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

                //initialize the CountShapes array
                CountShapes = new char[rows, cols];
                grid = new Grid(new Size(cols, rows), 20, new Point(20, 40));

                //populate the CountShapes array
                for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
                    {
                        CountShapes[r, c] = line[c];
                    }
                }

                //configure grid so each cell is drawn properly
                ConfigureGrid();

                //resize form to grid height and width
                this.Width = this.cols * grid.CellSize + 60;
                this.Height = this.rows * grid.CellSize + 80;

                //tell form to redraw
                this.Refresh();
            }    
        }

        private void ConfigureGrid()
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < this.rows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < this.cols; c++)
                {
                    //change colour of cell depending on what
                    //is in it
                    if (CountShapes[r, c] == '.')
                        grid.GetCell(r, c).BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                    else if (CountShapes[r, c] == 'X')
                        grid.GetCell(r, c).BackColor = Color.Purple;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            if (grid != null)
                grid.Draw(e.Graphics);
        }

        private bool SolveMaze(int r, int c)
        {                
            if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= this.rows || c >= this.cols)
            {
                Counter++;
                return false;
            }

            if (CountShapes[r, c] == '.')
            {

                return false;
            }                                    
                //move in all directions to find the end point
                if (SolveMaze(r + 1, c)) return true; //go Down
                if (SolveMaze(r, c + 1)) return true; //go Right
                if (SolveMaze(r, c - 1)) return true; //go Left
                if (SolveMaze(r - 1, c)) return true; //go Up

            //if made to here we are blocked in all direction
            //leave a marker because we will back out

                Counter++;    
                return true;                
        }

        private void mnuFileSolve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //solve maze
            SolveMaze(0, 0);
            ConfigureGrid();

            MessageBox.Show("" + Counter);

            this.Refresh();
        }        
    }
}
```

**Please Note: The Grid Class is being accessed from another file.**

Also is I am using a counter, which is not very good for recursion, so do you folks have any suggestions as to how I can remove it from my code, but keep the same functionality?

Comment: Did you try to step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: It's not working because you're immediately exiting if you don't find an 'X'. Your calling method (`mnuFileSolve_Click`). Should loop through each character in the input file and pass it to `SolveMaze`. This will get you a bit closer (but your counter will be wrong). You essentially need to store two buckets of points: One for the *current* shape being processed, and one for the *entire* file (since your search is recursively travelling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing because if your element on [0, 0] is not 'X' it will immediately exit. And in order to count shapes I would mark tiles as passed somehow. For example you can count those shapes on a cloned array and change counted shape back to '.':

```
private int SolveMaze(char[,] maze)
{
    var numberOfShapes = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            if (maze[r, c] == 'X')
            {
                numberOfShapes++;
                CleanTheShape(maze, r, c);
            }
        }
    }
    return numberOfShapes;
}

private void CleanTheShape(char[,] maze, int r, int c)
{
    if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= this.rows || c >= this.cols)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (maze[r, c] == '.') return;

    maze[r, c] = '.';

    CleanTheShape(maze, r + 1, c);
    CleanTheShape(maze, r, c + 1);
    CleanTheShape(maze, r, c - 1);
    CleanTheShape(maze, r - 1, c);
}
```

Usage:

```
var numberOfShapes = SolveMaze((char[,])(CountShapes.Clone()));
MessageBox.Show("" + numberOfShapes);
```

With that approach you will count every tile of the maze and if it is X - you will start a recursive routine to clean up that shape - so it would not counted again. I`ve updated the result and now you can get rid of your global Counter.

Comment: With your code here, how will where would I output the number of shapes then? As in, where would I place the messagebox?

Comment: Would be nice if you also could show how to get rid of the global counter

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Totally cleared it up! Thanks a ton bro @JleruOHeP

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
struct Point { public int X, Y; }
HashSet<Point> FindShapes(int x, int y, string[] lines, HashSet<Point> alreadyProcessed, HashSet<Point> currentShape = null)
{
    var thisPoint = new Point { X = x, Y = y };
    if (alreadyProcessed.Contains(thisPoint))
        return null; //Already processed
    if (lines.Length <= x || lines[x].Length <= y)
        return null; //Invalid co-ordinate
    if (lines[x][y] != 'X')
        return null; //Not an 'X'

    if (currentShape == null) //If currentShape is null, it means we're the first call to enter this shape
        currentShape = new HashSet<Point>();

    currentShape.Add(thisPoint);     //Mark this point as part of the shape
    alreadyProcessed.Add(thisPoint); //Mark this point processed

    FindShapes(x + 1, y, lines, alreadyProcessed, currentShape); //Check to the right
    FindShapes(x - 1, y, lines, alreadyProcessed, currentShape); //Check to the left
    FindShapes(x, y + 1, lines, alreadyProcessed, currentShape); //Check below
    FindShapes(x, y - 1, lines, alreadyProcessed, currentShape); //Check above

    return currentShape; //Return the set back
}
```

Then you use it as follows:

```
var lines = inFile.Split('\n');
var alreadyProcessed = new HashSet<Point>();
var results = new List<HashSet<Point>>();
for(var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    for(var j = 0; j < lines[i].Length; j++)
        results.Add(FindShapes(i, j, lines, alreadyProcessed));

var shapes = results.Where(d => d != null).ToList();

//Example of how to use the result. Number of shapes in shapes.Count
foreach(var shape in shapes)
{
    foreach(var point in shape)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(point.X + ", " + point.Y);
    }
}
```

Where `inFile` contains the full text of the file.

As it's most likely a homework question, I won't explicitly integrate it with your current solution - but hopefully this should get you started and you can tailor it to your needs. If it is indeed homework, I'd advise you not to copy and paste this code, but to use it as a reference and reason through the process

Answer (score 0):

Other answers address your specific problem. Mine is a non-recursive version. I do understand that it won't help you, because you are being taught recursion, but I'm posting it here because others may find it useful from general algorithms and data structure perspective.

There is something that is called [Union Find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) algorithm. Here is an [implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42573/is-this-unionfind-code-efficient) of it in C#.

We can use a very similar implementation like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A UnionFindNode represents a set of nodes that it is a member of.
/// 
/// You can get the unique representative node of the set a given node is in by using the Find method.
/// Two nodes are in the same set when their Find methods return the same representative.
/// The IsUnionedWith method will check if two nodes' sets are the same (i.e. the nodes have the same representative).
///
/// You can merge the sets two nodes are in by using the Union operation.
/// There is no way to split sets after they have been merged.
/// </summary>
public class UnionFindNode<T>
{
    private UnionFindNode<T> _parent;
    private uint _rank;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new disjoint node, representative of a set containing only the new node.
    /// </summary>
    public UnionFindNode(T value)
    {
        _parent = this;
        Value = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the current representative of the set this node is in.
    /// Note that the representative is only accurate untl the next Union operation.
    /// </summary>
    public UnionFindNode<T> Find()
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_parent, this)) _parent = _parent.Find();
        return _parent;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether or not this node and the other node are in the same set.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsUnionedWith(UnionFindNode<T> other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
        return ReferenceEquals(Find(), other.Find());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Merges the sets represented by this node and the other node into a single set.
    /// Returns whether or not the nodes were disjoint before the union operation (i.e. if the operation had an effect).
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True when the union had an effect, false when the nodes were already in the same set.</returns>
    public bool Union(UnionFindNode<T> other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
        var root1 = this.Find();
        var root2 = other.Find();
        if (ReferenceEquals(root1, root2)) return false;

        if (root1._rank < root2._rank)
        {
            root1._parent = root2;
        }
        else if (root1._rank > root2._rank)
        {
            root2._parent = root1;
        }
        else
        {
            root2._parent = root1;
            root1._rank++;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now, with this implementation you can implement your solver like this, non-recursively:

```
public static class Solver
{
    public static int Solve(string fileName, char shapeChar)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        var rows = int.Parse(lines[0]);
        var cols = int.Parse(lines[1]);
        lines = lines.Skip(2).ToArray();

        UnionFindNode<char>[] nodes = new UnionFindNode<char>[rows * cols];

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            string line = lines[r];
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {
                UnionFindNode<char> current = new UnionFindNode<char>(line[c]);
                nodes[c*rows + r] = current;
                if (c > 0)
                {
                    Combine(current, nodes[(c - 1) * rows + r], current.Value);
                }
                if (r > 0)
                {
                    Combine(current, nodes[c * rows + r - 1], current.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        return nodes.Where(x => x.Value == shapeChar).Select(x => x.Find()).Distinct().Count();
    }

    private static void Combine(UnionFindNode<char> current, UnionFindNode<char> n, char shapeChar)
    {
        if (n.Value == shapeChar)
        {
            n.Union(current);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Solver.Solve(@"yourpath.txt",'X'));
```

Here, we use Union Find to combine all cells with the same value in it. In your example you are interested in `X`s. We can similarly and easily use it to find all `.` shapes (in your example there will be 2 of them), or if we had more than just `X`s and dots: any other character, we could do these too.

Note, that *Find* method of `UnionFindNode` is recursive, so in certain (very stretched) sense you can call this solution recursive too.